# Load a package within a function

Tags: julia

Why isn't it possible to use `using` within a function?

How can I load a package from a function call? Thanks

```
function fn()
  using JSON
end

fn()
ERROR: error compiling fn: unsupported or misplaced expression "using" in function fn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (really) - conditional package loading is related to conditional dependencies which aren't currently really supported in Julia. This is a big discussion in the julia community. You can work around it with `@eval using JSON` but you may run into problems with this approach.

Only in rare cases should there actually be a use for this. Just `using JSON` at the beginning of your module.